# Checking Mutliple Values in Dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nltk

I am trying to do something very simple - I have a dictionary (sentence_dict) where the values are either a single sentence or a list of sentences. I am trying to check if two names are in a sentence and if so, create a new dictionary with that sentence as the value and the original sentence_dict key as the key.

However, when I try to do:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

name1 = 'Trump'
name2 = 'Gates'
mentioned_text_dict = {}

for k, v in sentence_dict.iteritems():
    for i in v:
        if name1 and name2 in i:
            mentioned_text_dict[k] = i
```

My resulting dictionary has values that are sentences with EITHER name1 or name2, not both.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us `sentence_dict`?

Comment: `if name1 in i and name2 in i:`

Comment: @mauricemeyer thank you, not sure why that was stumping me so much.